# Reflecting information about an AutoMapper mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Given the name of a property on the source type, I need to get the `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo` for the destination property.

```
PropertyInfo GetDestinationProperty<TSource, TDestination>(string sourceProperty)
{
    var map = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor(typeof(TSource), typeof(TDestination));
    // [magic]
    return result;
}
```

The problem I aim to solve is this: I have an MVC application. There is an Entity Framework model (the source type) that provides its own validation before saving the database context. There's a complex, multi-layered ViewModel that I'm mapping this EF model onto. I need to translate the EF validation errors into MVC view model validation errors so they show up nicely on the client. For example, if I get an EF error on the property "Description", I need to turn that into the mapped property "Info.Description".

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: Given EF model validation errors on the source type, I need to transfer them to the MVC ModelState for a complex mapping.

Comment: You need to specify that your are not using default mappings i.e. mappings by name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a solution, but the code is a little messy. To get the path to the destination property in a complex mapping, which I can then toss into the ModelState for errors, I can use this code:

```
    public string GetDestinationPath(Type source, Type destination, string propertyName)
    {
        return GetDestinationPath(source, destination, propertyName, string.Empty);
    }

    public string GetDestinationPath(Type source, Type destination, string propertyName, string path)
    {
        var typeMap = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor(source, destination);
        if (typeMap == null)
            return null;
        var maps = typeMap.GetPropertyMaps();
        var exactMatch = maps.FirstOrDefault(m => m.SourceMember != null && m.SourceMember.Name == propertyName);
        if (exactMatch != null)
            return path + exactMatch.DestinationProperty.Name;
        foreach (var map in maps)
        {
            if (map.SourceMember == null)
            {
                var result = GetDestinationPath(source, map.DestinationProperty.MemberType, propertyName, path + map.DestinationProperty.Name + ".");
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!(map.SourceMember is PropertyInfo))
                    continue;
                var result = GetDestinationPath((map.SourceMember as PropertyInfo).PropertyType, map.DestinationProperty.MemberType, propertyName, path + map.DestinationProperty.Name);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested but can you try this, assuming you have mapped it already.

```
var map = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<Source, Destination>();
        foreach( var propertMap in map.GetPropertyMaps() )
        {
            var dest = propertMap.DestinationProperty.MemberInfo;
            var source = propertMap.SourceMember;
        }

propertMap.GetSourceValueResolvers()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use simple reflection to achive that. Given that the properties names match in source and destination, you can write following code:

```
PropertyInfo GetDestinationProperty<TSource, TDestination>(string sourceProperty)
{
    var result = typeof(TDestination).GetProperty(sourceProperty);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: >Given that the properties names match in source and destination

This is not the case, which is why the problem doesn't have an obvious answer. I need to actually find the mapping.